# Mocking class attribute that is a class imported from another module unittest python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

**I have following project structure:**

```
├───pa
│   |───__init__.py
|   |─── a1.py
|   |─── test_a1.py
|
├───pb
│   |───__init__.py
|   |─── b1.py
```

With following code:
b1.py:

```
class B1:

    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "Unmocked_B1"

    def get_text(self):
        return self.text
```

pb.__init__.py:

```
from .b1 import B1
```

a1.py:

```
from src.pb import B1


class A1:

    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B1()

    def get_text(self):
        return self.b.get_text()
```

pa.__init__.py:

```
from .a1 import A1
```

**And I want to mock self.b in class A1 using unittest.mock.patch in such way that following code in test_a1.py will print "Mocked B1"**

test_a1.py:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch, PropertyMock
from . import A1


class TestB1(TestCase):

    @patch('Some args')
    def test_get_text(self, mocked_b1):
        # Some code
        
        a1 = A1()
        print(a1.get_text())  # Should print: Mocked B1
```

I tried both mocking B1 import with:

```
@patch('src.pb.b1.B1')
    def test_get_text(self, mocked_b1):
        mocked_b1.get_text.return_value = 'Mocked B1'

        a1 = A1()
        print(a1.get_text())  # Should print: Mocked B1
```

And mocking property of a1 with property mock:

```
@patch('pa.a1.A1.b', new_callable=PropertyMock)
    def test_get_text(self, mocked_b):
        mocked_b.get_text.return_value = 'Mocked B1'

        a1 = A1()
        print(a1.get_text())  # Should print: Mocked B1
```

Which does not seem to work even when I make attribute b inside A1 static instead of dynamic.

Is there a way to mock this attribute? It would be perfect if it would work on dynamic attribute as shown earlier.

I'm using python 3.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following syntax that uses `patch.object`and context manager (instruction `with`):

```py
class TestB1(TestCase):
    def test_get_text(self):
        a1 = A1()
        with patch.object(a1, "b") as mocked_b1:
            mocked_b1.get_text.return_value = 'Mocked B1'

            print(a1.get_text())  # Prints: Mocked B1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you frankfalse for answer of course similar solution with patch decorator also works (I discovered it this morning):

```
@patch('src.pa.a1.B1')
def test_get_text(self, mocked_B1):
    instance = mocked_B1.return_value
    instance.get_text.return_value = 'Mocked B1'

    a1 = A1()
    print(a1.get_text())  # Prints: Mocked B1
```

Don't know if there is solution with property mock

Comment: Your solution mocks the class `B1` **inside** the module `a1` and after that you get an instance of `B1`. It is an other example of Mocking in Python (a bit strange in my opinion). My solution (always in my opinion - but I'm not a guru!) mocks the attribute `b` of the instance a1 of class A1 and this seams what you ask in your question title.